# How to make Eclipse use an existing makefile that is not in root of project

Tags: c, eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to use Eclipse with an existing codebase. This code has the Makefile buried several directories deep from the root of the project sources. If I tell eclipse this buried directory is the root of the project, everything builds, but nothing indexes, since Eclipse does not know where the sources are.

If I tell Eclipse to use the root of the sources, then I have not been able to make Eclipse use the buried makefile.

I have read the other answers to the Eclipse makefile questions, but I still have a problem getting Eclipse to work perfectly - I have also tried a custom Builder schell script that uses the buried Makefile but no luck.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would try to change *build directory* of your project. In project properties: **C/C++ Build** -> **Builder Settings** -> **Build directory**.

[image]

Comment: @eriktous, or better `-C ...` to change the working directory too.

Comment: Sure, but that would accomplish the same as changing the build directory in the menu, like you showed in the answer (which I see as a nicer way of doing it). The choice between `-f` and `-C` depends on where you want the output files to go.

Comment: @eriktous, agree, bu this actually depends on a build system used, not all makefiles  are designed to support building in another directory...

Comment: If build comand is `make -f workspace:project/build/directory`, leave build directory not changed in the Properties menu,  will it generate the build output to the workspace:project/build/directory?  is it ok to pick one from `-C ...` or `setting in build directory` , no need to do them both? Another question, if specified `-f...` not specified `-C`, the output following the Makefile's dir?

Comment: When all settings are done, run `project/build` project from the menu in Eclipse, building is processing, how to redirect the output to the Eclipse's console?